# How do you specify multi-tasking support in RestKit 0.20.x?

Tags: restkit, restkit-0.20

RestKit used to support multi-tasking using the following code chunk:

```
RKRequest* request = [[RKClient sharedClient] post:@"/upload" delegate:self];
request.backgroundPolicy = RKRequestBackgroundPolicyContinue;
```

I am looking at the latest versions (0.20.x) and I don't see any reference to the background policy enum. Does anyone know how to call this in the latest version of RestKit?

EDIT: Per Wain's answer below, I have found that you can do this for a GET method as follows:

```
RKHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation = [[RKHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];    
[requestOperation setShouldExecuteAsBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:nil];

RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [[RKObjectRequestOperation alloc] initWithHTTPRequestOperation:requestOperation responseDescriptors:@[responseDescriptor]];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    // handle success
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    // handle failure
}];

[operation start];
```

But there does not seem to be an equivalent for POST, since the RKObjectManager POST method creates a RKObjectRequestOperation internally and does not provide access to it.

Does anyone know if there is a different way to set this? Otherwise I suppose I could create my own extension method that provides access to this setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything runs on the background as standard and then switches back to the main thread to call your completion handlers. You don't need to do anything to push the processing onto a background thread.

Edit:
Apologies for the misunderstanding. I understand that the background tasking now must be dealt with either outside of RestKit or by using AFNetworking.

If using the AFNetworking route, it's handled as part of `AFURLConnectionOperation` which offers the method `setShouldExecuteAsBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:`.

Posting is simply a wrapper around:

```
RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [self appropriateObjectRequestOperationWithObject:object method:RKRequestMethodPOST path:path parameters:parameters];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:success failure:failure];
[self enqueueObjectRequestOperation:operation];
```

So your easiest options for using the AFNetworking route are to subclass the `RKObjectManager` and override `postObject:` or just to create the `RKObjectRequestOperation` manually (in your own utility method). Then access the `RKObjectRequestOperation` `HTTPRequestOperation` property.

Comment: I was asking about multi-tasking, not multi-threading. You are correct that multi-threading happens by default, but multi-tasking is an iOS feature where you can subscribe to continue execution for a short time after your app has entered the background. That is what the background policy enum used to handle, and I am looking to see if it has a replacement as it no longer seems to exist.

Comment: That gets me really close! I am able to see how I could use setShouldExecuteAsBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler for a GET method, but the object that has this method is one layer too deep for me to configure for POST methods. I suppose I could write an extension method, but before I do are you aware of any way to configure this for a POST?